# Send and Receive POST Data - C++

Tags: c++, post

I want to send and receive POST Data in C++,
I tried with Curl but it have many dependencies and there it´s bad for my project.
If anyone can help me with a code it would be perfect,
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Are you aware that cURL for windows comes with all dependencies [statically compiled in](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)? And on \*nix systems it is almost always already installed. Also dependencies are a *good* thing. That is code you do not have to write, maintain, or fix security issues in.

Comment: I asked her for how can I add Curl as static but nobody answer me, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Building curl statically is very painful, especially as a new developer. What is the problem with shipping libcurl as a DLL like every other project out there? Is there a hidden requirement you're not telling us?

Comment: I only need link it correctly to CodeBlocks and link as static. Sorry for my poor details

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use [Casablanca](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-c-rest-sdk-casablanca/)

Partial code example:

```
    http_client client(YourUrl);                                                                             
    http_response httpResponse = client.request(methods::POST, L"/upload", Yourjson).get();              
    if (httpResponse.status_code() != status_codes::OK)                                              
    {
    ok = false;
    }
```

In the future please post what approaches have you tried, what was the specific fail and add code examples.

Comment: Can you help me for send a POST value, sorry, Im newbie in C++.

Comment: Please clarify your request, you need to POST? post what? json?

Comment: I have a form in my server that save post data in a txt, I need send data from PC to my server. Like hwid={DATA}

Comment: One of the options, is to generate json from the text you want to send after use the code in the response, fill your uri and the json you generated.